# Installing R package tm in amazon EMR

Tags: r, hadoop, amazon-web-services, emr, tm

I couldnt install the package `tm` in EMR. It seems some version issue. First I installed teh latest version tm 0.6. It is not supported by R 2.15.2 which is in the EMR. Then I try to install version tm 0.5-8.1. Now I'm getting the following error.

`dependency 'slam' is not available for package 'tm'`

Can you suggest me the correct package/packages to install `tm` in EMR Amason?

Comment: Generally, this kind of command `install.packages("tm", dependency=TRUE)` solves this kind of issue. Of course, you have to be careful as you are trying to install an old version of `tm`. The other solution is to install first the correct version of `slam` matching `tm` requirements.

Comment: Ya, I have installed first slam and then tm. It works. The problem is there are no documentation for old packages to find out the dependencies.